# Pull unique product id from a dataset and corresponding other column values to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a macro that can pull unique data from "Column A" but I also want the corresponding values from other columns of those unique values from Column A and I want them on a different spreadsheet. I tried using Worksheet Vlookup function in the code but it takes way too long for the dataset of over 70,000 rows and 42 columns. The code -

```
Sub UniqueProductDetails()

Dim ws1 as worksheet
Dim ws2 as worksheet

Ws1 = Worksheets(“Source”)
Ws2 = Worksheets(“Destination”)

SRow = Ws1.range(“A” & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 

Ws1.Range(“A1:A” & SRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, Unique=True, copytorange:=ws2.range(“A1”) 

'This code provides unique column A values in the Destination sheet

End Sub()
```

Data and Output is in this format
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Create Unique Column Data Worksheets

- In a nutshell, it will split the data by `ProductID` (column 1) into as many worksheets as there are (unique) `ProductID`s.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateProductWorksheets()

    ' Define constants.

    ' s - Source (read from)
    Const sName As String = "Source"
    Const sCriteriaColumn As Long = 1
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    ' d - Destination (write to)
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Turn off Autofilter.
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Reference the source (table) range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sFirstCellAddress).CurrentRegion
    ' Reference the source header row range ('shrrg')
    ' used to copy the column widths.
    Dim shrrg As Range: Set shrrg = srg.Rows(1)
    ' Reference the source criteria (one-column) range ('scrg').
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCriteriaColumn)
    
    ' Write the values from the source criteria DATA range,
    ' the source criteria range without the header, to an array ('cData').
    
    Dim cData As Variant
    cData = scrg.Resize(scrg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    
    ' Write the unique criteria values to a dictionary ('dict').
    
    ' Define a dictionary object ('dict') whose keys will hold
    ' the string representation of the unique values of the criteria array.
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case-insensitive i.e. 'A = a'
    
    Dim sKey As Variant ' Current Criteria Value (String)
    Dim r As Long ' Current Row in Criteria Array
        
    For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
        If Not IsError(cData(r, 1)) Then ' exclude error values
            ' Convert to string because 1.) 'AutoFilter' likes strings
            ' and 2.) if the worksheet names are numbers ('1, 2, 3...'),
            ' they might get mistaken for worksheet indexes below,
            ' in the continuation of the code ('Set dws = wb.Worksheets(sKey)').
            sKey = CStr(cData(r, 1))
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(sKey) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Copy data.
    ' Loop through the keys of the dictionary and on each iteration,
    ' filter the source worksheet by the key and copy the filtered
    ' range to a newly created worksheet.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet ' Current Destination Worksheet
    Dim dfCell As Range ' Current Destination First Cell
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        
        ' Attempt to reference the destination worksheet...
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Worksheets(sKey)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' ... and delete it if it exists.
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then ' destination worksheet exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Else ' destination worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
        End If
        
        ' Add and reference a new worksheet, the destination worksheet...
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        dws.Name = sKey ' ... and rename it.
        
        ' Reference the destination first cell.
        Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        
        ' Copy the column widths using just the source header row range.
        shrrg.Copy
        dfCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        dfCell.Select ' so the selection is not the destination header row
        
        ' Filter the source range.
        srg.AutoFilter sCriteriaColumn, sKey
        
        ' Copy the filtered range to the destination worksheet.
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfCell
        
        ' Clear the current filter.
        sws.ShowAllData
        
        ' Reset the destination worksheet variable for the next
        ' attempt to reference the destination worksheet to work correctly.
        Set dws = Nothing
        
    Next sKey
    
    ' Remove the filter.
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Select the source worksheet.
    sws.Select
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Product worksheets created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this with a formula as well:

```
=LET(newColumns,INDEX(tblData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblData)),{1,2,3,7,4}),
     UNIQUE(newColumns))
```

`newColumns` returns the table with the new column order

Then you can return the unique values.

[image]

Together with `VSTACK` you could add the header columns as well to the output (I don't have that version yet)

Using the formulas with VBA:

```vb
ub writeUniqueReorderedList()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

With ws2
    'ColumnHeaders
    .Range("A1").Formula2 = "=INDEX(tblData[#Headers],1,{1,2,3,7,4})"
    .Range("A2").Formula2 = "=LET(newColumns,INDEX(tblData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblData)),{1,2,3,7,4}), " & _
            "UNIQUE(newColumns))"
    
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
    
End Sub
```