# Load a filtered data set into array and call required columns in different sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a data that requires me to filter data according to first column and call the first column and respective columns in desired order in other sheet. I was thinking of doing it through Remove duplicate function and arrays.

Code:

```
Sub destroyerdups()
'Data of 5 columns to be filtered according to 1st column and call filtered 1st column and other columns in desired order to a new sheet
    rng = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet2.Range("A2:F" & rng).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

[image: Image for reference]

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Did you already look at using Advanced Filter as suggested already in your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73123349/478884

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/72948872/16578424 - there are two answers. I will vote to close this question as duplicate (better triplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull unique product id from a dataset and corresponding other column values to a new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948872/pull-unique-product-id-from-a-dataset-and-corresponding-other-column-values-to-a)